# Twilio voice call not working in react native

Tags: react-native, twilio-click-to-call

I am trying to using react-native-twilio-programmable-voice library for use Twilio voice call. I implemented library and setup code from server end I received access token and used this in below code:

```
initTwilio = async () => {
    const token = await this.getAuthToken();
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        await this.getMicrophonePermission();
    }
    await TwilioVoice.initWithToken(token);
    TwilioVoice.addEventListener('deviceReady', () => {
      console.log("device Ready");
      this.setState({ twilioInited: true });
    });
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') { //required for ios
        TwilioVoice.configureCallKit({
            appName: 'ReactNativeTwilioExampleApp',
        });
    }
  };
  makeCall = () => TwilioVoice.connect({ To: '+919929294578' });
```

When I press I didn't get "device ready" in output and nothing happened if anyone did that please advice so I can complete...Thanks!

Comment: I have fixed this if anyone having issue then please share i will resolve.

Comment: Please share the resolution.